# Is it possible to pass environment variables to Ember cli sass during build?

Tags: ember.js, sass, ember-cli, broccolijs

I am using ember-cli-sass

I want to define some sass variables depending on env variable.

my theme1.scss file

```
@if 'theme1' == process.env.THEME {
  $color-secondary: #eee;
  $color-primary: #ff0;
}
```

How can i send my env to the broccoli build process

and how can I access the env variables in sass script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

after tracing the code back thru the ember-cli-sass module 
to the base broccoli-sass code i found that we can pass functions to sass in sassOptions.

```
var sass = require('node-sass');
var app = new EmberApp({

  sassOptions: {
    functions: {
      variable: function () {
        return new sass.types.String(process.env.VARIABLE);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

and then we can use it as a method in sassScript

```
@if variable() == 'foo' {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I hope it will help someone. I browsed github searching what is variable 'sass' means, and that works for me: `var sass = require(process.sass.getBinaryPath(true));`

Comment: It can also be `var sass = require('sass')` if you're using the default Dart Sass implementation.

Comment: In a more recent version of Ember (4.7), using ember-cli-sass 11 (dart) I had to use this set-up:

`var sass = require('sass');`

`sassOptions: { functions: { 'emberenv()': function () { return new sass.SassString(EmberApp.env()); }, }, }`

So I could use it like this:

`$fontPath: '/fonts/'; @if emberenv() == 'production' { $fontPath: '/site/templates/app/fonts/';}`